# How can i hide first Picker Item of Picker in React Native?

Tags: react-native, picker

This is my sample code, in Android I cant select first Picker Item at first time, i have created one dummy item so i need to hide first field.

```
<Picker 
    selectedValue={ this.state.selectedValue }
    onValueChange={(item) => this.setState({selectedValue: item})}>
    <Picker.Item label={"Slect Any"} value={null} />
    <Picker.Item label={"item1"} value={'item1'} key={key} />
    <Picker.Item label={"item2"} value={'item2'} key={key} />
    <Picker.Item label={"item3"} value={'item3'} key={key} />
</Picker>
```

Any one help this.

Comment: Do you want to disable it or not have it viewed at all?

Comment: Yes I want to hide first element. Because of the first element can't select in android device at first time.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need your component to have an extra boolean field `canSelectAny` in the state:

```
<Picker 
    selectedValue={ this.state.selectedValue }
    onValueChange={(item) => this.setState({selectedValue: item})}>
    {this.state.canSelectAny && <Picker.Item label={"Select Any"} value={null} />}
    <Picker.Item label={"item1"} value={'item1'} key={key} />
    <Picker.Item label={"item2"} value={'item2'} key={key} />
    <Picker.Item label={"item3"} value={'item3'} key={key} />
</Picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the answer to your question

```
{this.state.loading = false ? (<Picker.Item label="Art" value="Art" />) :null}
```